# reading files and store the method line in an string array

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, arrays

I have a java file 'Arithmetic.java', in which i have 2 overridden method.

Now i wanted to read this file and i need to print all the method signature lines and have to put all the values in an array.

if i found same signature then i have to print overridden method found. once i find the overridden method i have to suffix the method name as methodName_overridden1, methodName_overridden2 and so on...

till now i am able to read the lines, able to read the method names as well. but while putting the entire method signatures into an array and the suffixing part , i am not able to proceed.

Please look after the comment line//Finds Method Name, Method Return Type

may be i am using wrong way.

any help is appreciable

my code goes here:

```
                //Finds Method Name, Method Return Type

                if(indexOfMethod >-1 && indexOfOpenBrace >-1){

                    //Finds Method signature Start

                    System.out.println("Print method line="+line.trim());
                    int methodLength=methodSignatures.length;

                    List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String>();

                    myList.add(line);
                    for (int i = 0; i < methodLength; i++) {
                        while(! (methodSignatures[i].equals(myList)))
                        {
                            methodSignatures[i]=methodName+"Override_1";
                        }
                        System.out.println("Signature:"+methodSignatures[i]);
                    }

                    //Finds Method signature End

                    String modified = line.substring(indexOfMethod, indexOfOpenBrace);
                    System.out.println("modified: "+modified);
                    String st[] = modified.split(" ");
                    methodName = st[st.length-1];
                    methodReturn=st[st.length-2];
                    System.out.println("methodName="+methodName);
                    System.out.println("methodReturn="+methodReturn);

                    //Get Method Parameter Types

                    paramLists=line.substring(indexOfOpenBrace+1, indexOfCloseBrace);
                    //System.out.println("Present Method Params are: " + paramLists);
                    methodParams=paramLists.split(",");
                    for (int i =0; i < methodParams.length ; i++){
                        methodParams[i]=methodParams[i].trim();
                        methodParams[i] = methodParams[i].substring(0, methodParams[i].indexOf(" "));
                        System.out.println("Splitted Method Parameter Types:" +methodParams[i]+":");
                    }
                }

                //Finds Project Code

                if(line.contains(this.projectCode)){
                    System.out.println("Found Fix as:"+line);
                    if(classFound){
                        // create FixDetails object.
                        fixDetails = new FixDetails(packageName, className, methodName);

                        // sets all required params.
                        fixDetails.setmParams(methodParams);
                        fixDetails.setmReturnType(methodReturn);
                        fixDetails.setParamLists(paramLists);

                        //System.out.println("fixDetails in JAGTool: " + fixDetails);
                        testCaseGenerator.generateTest(fixDetails);

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Class not found yet. Probably import statement");
                    }        
                }

            }//End Of While
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: i am stucked in the loop logic.not able to implement.

Comment: Please post code of only the non-working part.. Too much code attracts too few readers.

Comment: yeah sorry for that, will take care that next time. but i also mentioned to look the code after comment line  "//Finds Method Name, Method Return Type" for easier access.

Comment: any one please help me in solving this. i m stucked

Comment: you have not initialized the array. give say  String[] methodSignatures = new String[10]; Without initialization it will not work. If you do not know the size of the array in the beginning, use ArrayList.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: i dont want to initialize...as i dont know the size...is there any other way .

Comment: Use a list which can grow dynamically.

Comment: any example code will help me a lot...